# elasticutils + django, extract_document can return a nested dictionary?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticutils

I have many questions regarding elasticutils and not sure if creating an issue for each question in the github or not.

Question 1.

When you create a mapping for a django model, and the model has a foreign key,
can you return a dictionary for the foreign key in extract_document()?

```
@classmethod
def extract_document(cls, obj_id, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        obj = cls.get_model().objects.get(pk=obj_id)

    return {
        'id': obj.id,
        'title': obj.title,
        'main_post': {
            'id': obj.main_post.id,
            'raw_html': obj.main_post.raw_html,
            'user_id': obj.main_post.user.id
        },
        'deleted': obj.deleted
    }
```

Question 2.

Is there an equivalent of haystack's `load_all()` in elasticutils?